# why `nbytes, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)` always returns 0?

Tags: go

I've written a simple program that fetch a list of url to store them inside some files. In this example google and gmail. I always run same command in different software version. Program is stored inside goFetchAll: this is the name of compiled version of the algorithm.

- go build
- ./goFetchAll http://www.google.com http://www.gmail.com

> ```
> 0.23s        0  http://www.google.com
> 1.15s        0  http://www.gmail.com
> ```

The second number should be the number of bytes of content. But it is alway 0.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    ch := make(chan string)

    for _, url := range os.Args[1:] {
        go fetch(url, ch)
    }

    for range os.Args[1:] {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }

    secs := time.Since(start).Seconds()
    fmt.Sprintf("%.2fs elapsed\n", secs)
}

func fetch(url string, ch chan<- string) {
    start := time.Now()
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        ch <- fmt.Sprint(err)
        return
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        ch <- fmt.Sprintf("Cant catch content")
        return
    }

    nbytes, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        ch <- fmt.Sprintf("while reading %s: %v", url, err)
        return
    }

    secs := time.Since(start).Seconds()
    ch <- fmt.Sprintf("%.2fs  %7d  %s", secs, nbytes, url)

    // store on file
    filename := string(url)
    filename = strings.Replace(filename, ":", "", -1)
    filename = strings.Replace(filename, "//", "-", -1)
    filename = strings.Replace(filename, "/", "", -1)
    filename = strings.Replace(filename, ".", "-", -1)
    filename = "downloads/" + filename + ".html"

    f, err := os.Create(filename)
    f.Write(body)
    defer f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        ch <- fmt.Sprintf("while writing %s: %v", url, err)
        return
    }
}
```

I've also an older version of same script that actually works:

> ```
> 0.25s    10363  http://www.google.com
> 0.89s    66576  http://www.gmail.com
> ```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    ch := make(chan string)

    for _, url := range os.Args[1:] {
        go fetch(url, ch)
    }

    for range os.Args[1:] {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }

    fmt.Println("%.2fs elapsed\n", time.Since(start).Seconds())
}

func fetch(url string, ch chan<- string) {
    start := time.Now()
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        ch <- fmt.Sprint(err)
        return
    }

    nbytes, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
    resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        ch <- fmt.Sprintf("whioe reading %s: %v", url, err)
        return
    }

    secs := time.Since(start).Seconds()
    ch <- fmt.Sprintf("%.2fs  %7d  %s", secs, nbytes, url)
}
```

Can someone explain why the newest version always count 0 seconds?

---

My partial solution is the following. I've just request again `http.Get(url)`

```
resp, err := http.Get(url)
nbytes, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
defer resp.Body.Close() // dont leak resources
if err != nil {
    ch <- fmt.Sprintf("while reading %s: %v", url, err)
    return
}

resp, err = http.Get(url)
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    ch <- fmt.Sprintf("Cant catch content")
    return
}
```

Comment: In your code the second number is the `nbytes` variable. Or does the older script really take 18.5 hours (66576 seconds) to run?

Comment: Thank you, ... I've update the question with new title and a better description. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because you've already read the response at the time of that call once. So the second time, 0 bytes are read from the stream. After the error checking calls are removed:

```
resp, err := http.Get(url)
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
nbytes, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
```

Note the `ReadAll` call on the second line.

One more small suggestion I'd like to propose (not related to the actual question) is to use the `defer` calls right after initialising the stream. For instance:

```
resp, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    ch <- fmt.Sprint(err)
    return
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Although not mentioned specifically, it can be inferred from [this section in Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#defer). Paraphrasing here:

> Second, it means that the close sits near the open, which is much clearer than placing it at the end of the function.

Comment: Yeah!!! I've just inverted `nbytes, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)` and `body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)`. Good Thank you for the answer!

Comment: But, .. how can I read the content and then count the amount of bytes?

Comment: Not entirely sure. `body` holds a byte array. You *can* find out the length of that using `len` but this is probably not what you want. I checked the values, and there was a difference of around 56, with `io.Copy` returning a higher value.

Comment: correction: the comment about difference is my mistake.